# Accessing the elements of a list 1 by 1

Tags: python

I have a variable in list format in which there are number of paths. I want to access each path 1 by 1 to write my output on that path

I have created a list which will have all the paths

```
    folders = glob(test_img_path)
    print(folders)

###############OUTPUT of FOLDERS Variable################

['C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\Target_images_new\\video_tiger_23sec', 'C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\Target_images_new\\video_tiger_leopard']

####################END#################################

##############LINE ON WHICH THE PATH WILL BE USED TO WRITE OUTPUT######

    cv2.imwrite(folders+"\\{}.jpg".format(img_name),image)

###########END############
```

There will be many paths in this folders variable. How can i modify my code to access these paths 1 by 1 from this list to write my final output on that path

Comment: Just put that statement in a for loop iterating over `folders`.

Comment: @Jan        for k in folders:
            cv2.imwrite(folders[k]+"\\{}.jpg".format(img_name),image) this throws an error. TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop through the list and write to the path

```
folders = glob(test_img_path)
for folder in folders:
    image = cv2.imread(...)
    ...
    cv2.imwrite(folder + "\\{}.jpg".format(img_name), image)
```

Comment: @ M Yousuf This script writes the data only to the last folder in the loop

Comment: Have you indented the code correctly? Because that's not possible. I guess you have written the cv2.imwrite line outside the for loop

Comment: @M Yousuf Sorry brother. It was error on my end about the indentation. Your suggestion works completely fine. But the images of folder 1 get repeated while writing the images of folder2. I guess another indentation issue but not able to figure out. Can i share my complete code script with u if u r ok with it?